# Debugging Makefile project of Linux Development with C++

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2015, makefile, remote-debugging

I can debug Console Application project of Linux Development with C++, but CANNOT debug Makefile project. The breakpoint is NOT hit.

My system is as in the following

- Window 10 home
- Visual Studio Community 2015 update 3
- Visual C++ for Linux Development 1.0.7
- VirtualBox 5.1.30 r118389 (Qt5.6.2) - CentOS 7 1708

New project -> Visual C++ -> Cross Platform -> Linux -> Console Application(Linux)
I can create project and it works well.

However, I CANNOT debug makefile project.

I tried as follows

1. Create project
   New project -> Visual C++ -> Cross Platform -> Linux -> Makefile Project(Linux)
   Name: Project1
   Location: D:\WorkSpace\TEST_LINUX\
   Solution name: Project1
2. Add source
   Click right "my Project(Project1 (Linux) )" -> Add ->  New Item... -> C++ File (.cpp)
   Name: main.cpp
   D:\WorkSpace\TEST_LINUX\Project1\Project1
3. Create empty Makefile
   d:\WorkSpace\TEST_LINUX\Project1\Project1\Makefile
4. Add Makefile
   Click right "my Project(Project1 (Linux) )" -> Add ->  Existing Item...
   File name: Makefile
5. Edit main.cpp and Makefile

   main.cpp

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
   {
       printf("Hello world 1\n");
       printf("Hello world 2\n");
       printf("Hello world 3\n");
       printf("Hello world 4\n");
       printf("Hello world 5\n");

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Makefile

   ```
   all:
       gcc -o Project1 main.cpp

   clean:
       rm -rf Project1
   ```
6. Config properties
   Click right "my Project(Project1 (Linux) )" -> Properties
   Edit    Configuration Properties -> General -> Remote Build Root Directory
       `~/projects` -> `/home/mike/projects`

   Edit    Configuration Properties -> Remote Build -> Build Command Line
        -> `cd $(RemoteRootDir)/$(ProjectName); make all`
   Edit    Configuration Properties -> Remote Build -> Rebuild All Command Line
        -> `cd $(RemoteRootDir)/$(ProjectName); make clean all`
   Edit    Configuration Properties -> Remote Build -> Clean Command Line
        -> `cd $(RemoteRootDir)/$(ProjectName); make clean`
   Edit    Configuration Properties -> Remote Build -> Outputs
        -> `$(RemoteRootDir)/$(ProjectName)/Project1`
7. Breakpoint
   Put cursor on a line("printf("Hello world 2\n");" and "printf("Hello world 5\n");") and press F9
8. Debug
   Click "Remote GDB Debugger"
9. Output window
   Seeing last line, this program works well but debugging does NOT works.

   Output -> show output from: Debug

   ```
   =thread-group-added,id="i1"
   GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9
   Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
   and "show warranty" for details.
   This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-pc-mingw32 --target=x86_64-linux-gnu".
   Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
   <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
   Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
   <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
   For help, type "help".
   Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
   Loaded 'shared libraries loaded at this time.'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
   Stopped due to shared library event:
     Inferior loaded /lib64/libc.so.6
       /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
   Loaded '/lib64/libc.so.6'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
   Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
   [Inferior 1 (process 8809) exited normally]
   The program '' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
   ```
10. Modify main.cpp

    ```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        printf("Hello world 1\n");
        getchar();
        printf("Hello world 2\n");
        getchar();
        printf("Hello world 3\n");
        getchar();
        printf("Hello world 4\n");
        getchar();
        printf("Hello world 5\n");

        return 0;
    }
    ```
11. Retry debugging
    Click "Remote GDB Debugger"

    Linux Console Window appears.

    ```
    Process /home/mike/projects/Project1/Project1 created; pid = 9353
    Listening on port 4444
    Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
    Hello world 1
    ```

    Press [Enter] in Linux Console Window

    ```
    Process /home/mike/projects/Project1/Project1 created; pid = 10152
    Listening on port 4444
    Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
    Hello world 1



    Hello world 2
    Hello world 3
    ```

    Press [Enter] in Linux Console Window

    ```
    Process /home/mike/projects/Project1/Project1 created; pid = 10152
    Listening on port 4444
    Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
    Hello world 1



    Hello world 2
    Hello world 3



    Hello world 4
    Hello world 5

    Child exited with status 0
    GDBserver exiting
    ```

Something strange

1. Although I press [Enter] twice, debugging finished.
   Running program in putty and pressing [Enter] four times, program finish.
2. Breakpoint is a white dot.
   Before clicking "Remote GDB Debugger", the breakpoint appears as a RED dot.
   But after clicking ["Remote GDB Debugger"], the breakpoint appears as a WHITE dot.
   Tooltip of white dot is "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained."
3. Every time, this project is out of date.
   Whenever I click "Remote GDB Debugger",  dialog box appears.

   ```
   Microsoft Visual Studio
   This project is out of date
   Would you like to build it?
   ```

   I NERVER modify my source. It is not out of date.

What can I do, in order to debug in Makefile Project (Linux) as well as Consol Application (Linux)?

Thank you for your appreciation in advance.

I mailed to vccplinux-support@microsoft.com but was mailed back `550 5.4.1 [vccplinux-support@microsoft.com]: Recipient address rejected: Access denied [BL2NAM06FT015.Eop-nam06.prod.protection.outlook.com]`

Comment: I figured out. I compared Consol Application project and Makefile project. Difference is compile option(-gdwarf-2).